# In java, how to read an unsigned data type from a byte type

Tags: java

I have two byte type data,(For example,they are "0xFB" and "0X03").

I hope to get an Integer type data from that two byte type data,(That becomes "0xFB03").

But,in java ,byte type data is a signed data.

Therefore, it has become such:

```
byte b1=0xFB,b2=0x03;
int i=(b1<<8)+b2;
System.out.println(i);
```

Its result is -1277(0xFFFFFB03),not what I wanted 64259(0xFB03).

So, how to read an unsigned data type from a byte type,in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java tends to convert `byte` and `short` operands to `int` before using them as arguments to operators.  A `byte` is a signed 8-bit integer type; thus, when converting a `byte` value whose uppermost bit is 1 to an `int`, the result will be a negative integer, in this case `16xFFFFFFFB`.

You can use a wider integer type as others have suggested.  But if you need to use a `byte` for some reason, the way to handle this is something like

```
int i = (((int)b1 & 0xFF) << 8) + ((int)b2 & 0xFF);
```

[I don't think the `(int)` conversions are necessary, but they're helpful to readers who may not be aware of Java's binary numeric promotion rules.]

The masking, to work with a value in the range 0-255, must be done immediately after the byte is converted to an `int`.  It won't work to do the calculation and then apply a mask to the result (try it when `b2` is in the 0x80-0xFF range).

Using Java 8, you can also do this:

```
int i = (Byte.toUnsignedInt(b1) << 8) + Byte.toUnsignedInt(b2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just read a `short` data type. It has 16 bytes, and should do what you want. There is no such thing as an unsigned byte in java.

Answer (score 2):

The typical approach in Java, if you want to extend a `byte` to a wider data-type without sign extension, is to apply `& 0xff` (bit-wise `and` with a bitmask of 8 ones) so the sign-extended version of the byte is again truncated to the lower 8 bit.

That makes your code:

```
byte b1 = (byte)0xFB, b2=0x03;
int i = ((b1 & 0xff) << 8) + (b2 & 0xff);
System.out.println(i);
```

Because Java doesn't have an unsigned 8-bit data-type, this is practically standard idiom: you will find this a lot in code that deals with constructing bigger numeric data types out of byte arrays.

*Note:* your original source code doesn't compile. The expression `byte b1=0xFB` isn't valid because `0xFB` is bigger than the maximum value of a byte (127). Fix it by forcibly casting 0xFB to a byte: `byte b1 = (byte)0xFB`